# Bounded second derivative of solution to first order differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I am studying numeric solutions of differential equations, and part of my reading is found in Simmonds' book, *Differential Equations with Applications and Historical Notes*. Although the chapter on numerical methods is written by John S. Robertson.

In the treatment of Euler's method, he states that the second derivative of the solution $y$ is bounded by some constant $M$. What am I missing that makes it necessary that the solution of a first order differential equation even be twice differentiable?

For some context, the differential equations under consideration are those of the form $y' = f(x, y)$, defined on some interval $[a, b]$, with some initial value $y(a) = \alpha$.

These are then transformed into the integral equation

$$
y(x_1) - y(x_0) = \int_{x_0}^{x_1} f(x, y) \, dx \text{.}
$$

Then, using Taylor's theorem and substituting back into that formula, the error is found to be

$$
\frac{h^2}{2} y''(\xi) \text{,}
$$

which I understand to be true. For the remainder of the method, this quantity is neglected. But in the next section, it simply states that the quantity $y''(x)$ is bounded on the entire interval, and so, by extension, is $y''(\xi)$. I don't understand why this is necessarily true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need some condition to be satisfied (e.g. $f(t,y)$ is continuous, and Lipschitz in the $y$ variable) to be sure that the solution exists, and is continuous on the interval.

Then since $y' = f(t,y)$, it follows that $y'$ exists, and is continuous on the interval.

Then see that $y'' = \frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(t,y) + y'\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(t,y)$.  If we know that the partial derivatives of $f$ are continuous, we can see that $y''$ is continuous on the interval.

Any continuous function on a closed interval is bounded.

You can iterate this method to get higher derivatives as well if needed.